# Determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ is an unbiased estimator for the variance $Var(X)$ of $X$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, parameter-estimation

consider a random variable $X$, whose mean value is known  and stochastically independent repetitions $X_1,...,X_n$ of $X$.
For each vector $\overrightarrow{a}=(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{n} \text{ with } a_i > 0 $ we denote with $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ the estimator 
$$T_\overrightarrow{a} = a_1 . (X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2 . (X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n . (X_n-\mu)^2$$  for the variance of X.

a) Determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ is an unbiased estimator for the variance $Var(X)$ of $X$.

b) Determine the most effective among the unbiased estimators $T_\overrightarrow{a}$.

**My thoughts**

a) 
$$Var(T_\overrightarrow{a}
) = a_1^2 . Var((X_1-\mu)^2) + a_2^2 . Var((X_2-\mu)^2) + ... + a_n^2 . Var((X_n-\mu)^2)     \\ 
 = a_1^2 . Var((X-\mu)^2) + a_2^2 . Var((X-\mu)^2) + ... + a_n^2 . Var((X-\mu)^2)     \\ 
 =(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2) . Var((X-\mu)^2)   \\
$$

I know, how to determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ is an unbiased estimator for the expected value $E(X)$ of $X$, but how can I do the same variance $Var(X)$ of $X$?

Every advice to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: What is the variance is what I am asking. Is $T_a$ supposed to be an estimator for $Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$ (say)?

Comment: yes, $Var(X_i)$ should be equal to $\sigma^2$, I guess. I thought, this is always the case for this task, isn't it?
I am not quite sure, as this is not explicitly mentioned in the task.

Comment: If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed, then $Var(T)=\sum a_i^2Var(X_i-\mu)^2=c\sum a_i^2$ for some constant $c$. You have to minimize $Var(T)$ subject to $E(T)=\sigma^2$.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that, but how can I find out if they are identical or not?

Comment: That information should be provided by you from context. Actually this looks like a version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433326/321264) problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108676/discussion-between-slamath-and-stubbornatom).

Comment: @StubbornAtom, i tried to solve the task using your tip, but didn't get much further.